# DAX YTD Previous Years based in a different Calendar

Tags: powerbi

I want to calculate YTD until the last month for the last years for sales by Year and Category, but I have a requisite.

I have a [Dim Date] dimension and an Order table like below.

| Date | DateKey | Day of Month | Month Number | Month Name | Year Number | Company Month Num | Company Month | Company Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27/09/2023 00:00 | 20230927 | 27 | 9 | September | 2023 | 9 | September | 2023 |
| 28/09/2023 00:00 | 20230928 | 28 | 9 | September | 2023 | 9 | September | 2023 |
| 29/09/2023 00:00 | 20230929 | 29 | 9 | September | 2023 | 9 | September | 2023 |
| 30/09/2023 00:00 | 20230930 | 30 | 9 | September | 2023 | 9 | September | 2023 |
| 01/10/2023 00:00 | 20231001 | 1 | 10 | October | 2023 | 9 | September | 2023 |
| 02/10/2023 00:00 | 20231002 | 2 | 10 | October | 2023 | 10 | October | 2023 |
| 03/10/2023 00:00 | 20231003 | 3 | 10 | October | 2023 | 10 | October | 2023 |
| 04/10/2023 00:00 | 20231004 | 4 | 10 | October | 2023 | 10 | October | 2023 |

| Sales | OrderDate | Datekey | CategoryName | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 114 | 10/06/2022 00:00 | 20220610 | Seafood | 2022 |
| 52 | 23/09/2022 00:00 | 20220923 | Condiments | 2022 |
| 228 | 01/10/2022 00:00 | 20221001 | Beverages | 2022 |
| 803 | 01/11/2022 00:00 | 20221101 | Seafood | 2022 |
| 155 | 23/11/2022 00:00 | 20221123 | Beverages | 2022 |
| 155 | 03/12/2022 00:00 | 20221203 | Seafood | 2022 |
| 155 | 15/12/2022 00:00 | 20221215 | Condiments | 2022 |
| 52 | 21/02/2023 00:00 | 20230221 | Seafood | 2023 |
| 114 | 22/03/2023 00:00 | 20230322 | Seafood | 2023 |
| 596 | 02/05/2023 00:00 | 20230502 | Condiments | 2023 |
| 155 | 03/05/2023 00:00 | 20230503 | Beverages | 2023 |
| 114 | 04/05/2023 00:00 | 20230504 | Seafood | 2023 |
| 155 | 26/08/2023 00:00 | 20230826 | Beverages | 2023 |
| 114 | 19/10/2023 00:00 | 20231019 | Condiments | 2023 |

As you can see my [Dim Date] has Company Month, because some days in the month beginning or ending can belong to a different month so we need to consider it to calculate the sales amount.
Following the data in my tables I want the following result considering today is October 26th 2023

|  | 2022 | 2023 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Beverages | 228 | 310 |
| Condiments | 52 | 596 |
| Seafoof | 114 | 280 |

I used the following approach but doesn't work, can you advise me, please?

```
YTD1 = TOTALYTD([Sales],'Dim Date'[Date])

YTD SPPYs1 = 

var LastMonth = MONTH(today())-1

var LastDateofLastMonth = CALCULATE(Max('Dim Date'[Date]),'Dim Date'[Company Month Num]=LastMonth)

VAR month = MONTH(LastDateofLastMonth )

VAR day = DAY(LastDateofLastMonth )

return

CALCULATE(
    [YTD],
    'Dim Date'[Month Number]<=month&&
    'Dim Date'[Day of Month]<=day)
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you wanting the equivalent of `TOTALYTD([Sales],'Dim Date'[Date])` but taking into consideration the company month and to only include completed company months?

Comment: Hi Sam exactly, This is what I want to calculate for previous years.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Sales YTD = 
  var todayCompanyMonth = LOOKUPVALUE('Dim Date'[Company Month Num], 'Dim Date'[Date], TODAY())
  var todayCompanyYear = LOOKUPVALUE('Dim Date'[Company Year], 'Dim Date'[Date], TODAY())
  var selectedCompanyYear = SELECTEDVALUE('Dim Date'[Company Year], todayCompanyYear)

  var result = CALCULATE(SUM('Order'[Sales]), 'Dim Date'[Company Year] = selectedCompanyYear && 'Dim Date'[Company Month Num] < todayCompanyMonth)

  RETURN result
```

Comment: Hi Sam,

Thank you for your reply I used your code and worked perfectly for my case, I just needed to do a minus 1 to the company month because I wanted the last closed month.

Comment: This part should `'Dim Date'[Company Month Num] < todayCompanyMonth` should handle last closed month, so no need for - 1. Please accept the answer above for the benefit of all.